# press hotkey to skip li not working jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `li` arrangement that represents an online exam.

If the student click on a random li, and dont know the answer, he can skip to the next question (li) by making click on its respective `li` or just pressing the number 5 in his keyboard.

This is the code I made so far.

**PROBLEM**

i need to detect the current opened li (focused input) and if press the number 5 in the keyboard, skip to the next li and open it up to work in it

```js
 
$("li").on("click",function(){
 $("li").find("input").hide();
$(this).find("input").show().focus();

});


var body = $('body');

    body.keypress( function (e) {
  
    var li =  $(document).find('ul.list li');

    
 
 if ( e.which == 53 ) {
  //alert()
  li.find("input").next().show();
 }
 
 
 
 
});
```

```css
li input{display:none;}
li{cursor:pointer;border:1px solid red;margin:5px;padding:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='list'>

<li>a <input value='' /></li>
<li>b <input value='' /></li>
<li>c <input value='' /></li>
<li>d <input value='' /></li>
<li>e <input value='' /></li>
<li>f <input value='' /></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `document.activeElement` to get the active `input` element. Once you get the `input` instance, use the `closest()` to get `li` and `next()` to move to the next `li`.

```js
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $("li").find("input").hide();
  $(this).find("input").show().focus();

});

$('body').keypress(function(e) {

  if (e.which == 53) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let li, input;
    if (document.activeElement.tagName == "BODY") {
      input = $('li input').first();
    } else {
      li = $(document.activeElement).closest('li');
      input = li.next().find("input");
    }

    input.show();
    input.focus();
  }
});
```

```css
li input {
  display: none;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='list'>

  <li>a <input value='' /></li>
  <li>b <input value='' /></li>
  <li>c <input value='' /></li>
  <li>d <input value='' /></li>
  <li>e <input value='' /></li>
  <li>f <input value='' /></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: pretty good answer my friend. thank you. According to your function... how do I  open the first li (default), by pressing the 5 hotkey in case no input be focused?

Comment: @max if the active element is the `body` tag, then first input needs to be focused. Have edited the code, thanks.

Comment: terrific. works like a charm my friend in my site. thank you very much.